# Solving systems of logial and set theoretic propositions

Tags: logic, sets

I need to allocate a couple of dozen elements into different sets, respecting some boundary conditions, and was hoping *Mathematica* might somehow help.

A simple example:

The propositions being

a) a $\in$(AvB)

b) b $\in$B

c) $\vert$$A\vert$=1

I would expect the answer to be: A={a}, B={b}.

Any hints? Thanks, indeed.

Comment: What you've given us is a simple *description* of a simple example, not actually a simple example. Your description is great, but we need more *Mathematica*-specific details in the *example*. Please provide us with a simple example of what `A`, `B`, `a`, and `b` could be, in, say, `List` form. Or, is that you want *Mathematica* to logically deduce the result from the *propositions*? (In other words, are you asking *Mathematica* to do logical deductions, or are you asking it to sort elements into lists?) By the way, I think you need to add "d) a != b".

Comment: @march Thanks for your comment! It is the latter: I want the program to logically deduce the result as it stands from exactly these propositions (plus the one you added). However, if there is another way around it, I would certainly appreciate to learn about it, too. In the end, I simply need to know which element has to be in which set such that all boundary conditions are met.

Comment: All right, so maybe start [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TheoremProving.html). (I've never used *Mathematica* for this, so I can't help. If it had been the former of my two guesses, I would've been able to help (most of us would have, actually).)